# NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1002 when trying to encode URL in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, url

I was trying to encode a URL. The code works fine when I encode files in my bundle. But when I tried to encode the files written to Documents and Cache, the program fails to encode.

Here is my encoder:

```
private class func EncodeURL(_ url:URL,encoding:UInt) ->String {
    do{
        return try NSString(contentsOf: url, encoding: encoding) as String
    }catch{}

    return ""
}
```

I'm using the following three:

```
content = EncodeURL(url, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
content = EncodeURL(url, encoding: 0x80000632)
content = EncodeURL(url, encoding: 0x80000631)
```

And none of them work.

Here is the code I use to generate files. I'm putting them in the Documents Folder.

```
func writeFile(fileName:String,data:NSData)->Bool{

    guard let filePath = createFilePath(fileName: fileName) else{
        return false
    }
    return data.write(toFile:filePath,atomically:true)
}

func createFilePath(fileName:String)->String?{
    let dir = getCachePath() 
    if(!dirExists(dir: dir) && !createDir(dir: dir)){
        return nil
    }
    let filePath = dir + fileName
    if(fileExists(path: filePath)){
        do{
            try getFileManager().removeItem(atPath: filePath)
        }catch{
            return nil
        }
    }
    return filePath
}

func getCachePath()->String{
    var cacheDir = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true).first!
    if(!cacheDir.hasSuffix("/")){
        cacheDir += "/"
    }
    cacheDir += CACHEPATH + "/" //CACHEPATH is just NSHomeDirectory()
    return cacheDir
}

writeFile(fileName: String(timeInterval)+"_"+somestring+".txt", data: data! as NSData)
```

Above is how I generate the files.

And how I passed URL is:

```
url = URL(string:getCachePath()+bookname+".txt")
```

passing this to

```
EncodeURL(url:URL,encoding:UInt)
```

My URL is:

> /Users/houki/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/67C921C8-18A3-4A3F-81FF-C3AF04E88049/data/Containers/Data/Application/85633861-90E6-4DB8-95B0-86C359C74C6B/Documents//Users/houki/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/67C921C8-18A3-4A3F-81FF-C3AF04E88049/data/Containers/Data/Application/85633861-90E6-4DB8-95B0-86C359C74C6B/1511757881.83107_bigbrother.txt

Does this look weird? I'm testing it on a simulator though.

But actually this worked just fine when I tried to read files through the path. The following code is working.

```
let contentsofPath = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: getCachePath())
```

Comment: Your URL isn't valid. Show how you create the URL you are passing to your `EncodeURL` method.

Comment: Your update does not show how you create the `URL` that you pass to `EncodeURL`.

Comment: Added. But actually the URL worked just fine when I tried to fetch its contents using contentsOfDirectory.

Comment: You are confusing file paths and URLs. Some APIs take a file path as an argument, some take a URL as an argument. They are not the same thing.

Comment: You are also appending NSHomeDirectory to the documents directory. Look at your url again.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are not creating your `URL` correctly. You are passing a path to the `string` argument. You need to use the `URL(fileURLWithPath:)` initializer.

```
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
```

Only use the `URL(string:)` initializer if the string you pass is a valid URL beginning with a URL scheme.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone still looking for a solution on Objective-C,

If you are trying to access the bundle file, to create NSURL you'll have to use

> fileURLWithPath

instead

> URLWithString

.
Usually, -1002 error suggests, the URI is invalid.

For Objective-C, below can be the code -

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:resourceURL];
```

later, you can utilize this URI in your code.

Answer (score 0):

It could also be because your url is not `https`

Add this in your plist

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
<key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
<true/>
</dict>
```

or get the secure version of `http` url

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. A simple Single view app running on iphone 6s simulator gave error 1022 until I added Allow Arbitrary loads. my url was not local to Iphone, but to an external url though. Thanks
[image: info.plist snapshot]